# How to make the timer start from 1 to 50000 millisecond in rust?

Tags: rust

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
hookmap = "0.4.7"
delay_timer = "0.10.1"
```

main.rs

```
use hookmap::*;

use delay_timer::prelude::*;
use anyhow::Result;
use smol::Timer;
use std::time::Duration;



fn main() {

    let hotkey = Hotkey::new();

    hotkey!(hotkey => {
       
        modifier(F1) {

            //1、When I press F1，the timer start from 1 to 50000 millisecond. how to implement this.
            //let mut current_time= 1;


            //2、if the current_time equals some numbers, do somethings.
            if current_time =2000 {
                //do something 1
            } 
            if current_time =39999 {
                //do something 2
            } 
            //...
         
           
        }
    });

    hotkey.handle_input();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `key_press` of `F1` to the creation of a `DelayTimer` which will
execute the various tasks you need after a defined duration has passed.

The following code will create a separate timer every time the `F1` key is pressed. Every scheduled task will print a line after 2000, 39999 and 50000 ms. Since it is not specified, with this solution it is possible that two instances of the created task runs at the same time.

```
use hookmap::*;
use anyhow::Result;
use delay_timer::prelude::*;
use std::time::Duration;
use smol::Timer;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let hotkey = Hotkey::new();

    hotkey!(hotkey => {
            on_press F1 => |_event| {
                let delay_timer = DelayTimerBuilder::default().build();
                // Create the task
                // A chain of task instances.
                let task_instance_chain = delay_timer.insert_task(build_task_async_print().unwrap()).unwrap();

                // Get the running instance of task 1.
                let task_instance = task_instance_chain.next_with_wait().unwrap();

                // This while loop avoids removing the task before it completes
                while task_instance.get_state() != delay_timer::prelude::instance::COMPLETED {};

                // Remove task which id is 1.
                delay_timer.remove_task(1).unwrap();
            };

    });

    hotkey.handle_input();
    Ok(())
}

// Actually build the task
fn build_task_async_print() -> Result<Task, TaskError> {
    let mut task_builder = TaskBuilder::default();

    // This is the function in which you want to wait
    let body = create_async_fn_body!({

        Timer::after(Duration::from_millis(2000)).await;
        println!("First something");

        Timer::after(Duration::from_millis(39999)).await;
        println!("Second something");

        Timer::after(Duration::from_millis(50000)).await;
        println!("Timer end");
    });

    // Build the task and assign 1 to it
    task_builder
        .set_task_id(1)
        .spawn(body)
}
```

Mind that this solution works only on Windows since the `hookmap` crate supports only that OS.

Comment: Thanks very much.
Since the time of pressing  F1 is not accurate, so I want to add an offset, after pressing  F1, timer start to work, In this process, when pressing F3, the timer goes forward 100 milliseconds, and when pressing F2, the timer goes backward 100 milliseconds. Could you help me again?